# Does my time studying for masters and PhD degrees count towards citizenship in Germany?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, citizenship, study

I am a masters student currently in my 2nd year in Germany. I have been accepted to a 5 year PhD program, also in Germany, that will be funded through a job position at the university.

My question: Does my whole 7 year stay in Germany during the 2 year masters degree along with the 5 year PhD count towards permanent residence or citizenship?

Comment: For the **permanent residence** it is the 5 years of working that counts (60 months of contributions to the pension system). For **citizenship** the whole time will be counted.

Comment: Special exemption applies: Working 2 years is enough if you obtained a Masters degree in Germany (for permanent residence).

Comment: §18c Abs. 1 AufenthG.

Answer (score 2):

Yes those years do count towards citizenship. You will need to switch to a different status and do so before applying for citizenship though. That's a non-issue since you can get a different residence permit the minute you get a job offer from a non-university employer.

Answer (score 0):

Practical advise for citizenship: apply already when you reach your 5th total year of residence in Germany. Use a B2 language certificate as special integration.